# Blazor Web Assembly failing on AuthenticationContext for secure API access

Tags: active-directory, authorization, blazor-webassembly, adal

I have ported a Blazor server application over to WASM and the authority to contact an API is failing on the AuthenticationContext part of the authorisation for access to a secured API.

```
public class SomeClass
{
      private readonly CommsSettings _settings;
      private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
      private AuthenticationContext _authContext;
      private ClientCredential _clientCredential;

      public SomeClass(HttpClient client, CommsSettings settings, ILoggingService   loggingService)
      {
          _settings = CommsSettings;
          _loggingService = loggingService;
          var token = RetrieveTokenAsync(_settings);

          _httpClient = client;       
      }

      public static async Task<string> RetrieveTokenAsync(CommsSettings settings)
      {
          //Fails here
          var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext($"{settings.Authority}");

        try
        {
            AuthenticationResult result = null;                
        
            var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(settings.ClientId, settings.AppKey);
            result = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(settings.ResourceId, clientCredential).ConfigureAwait(false);
           if (result == null)
           {
               throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to obtain the JWT token");
           }

           return result.AccessToken;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not retrieve token.", ex);
        }
  }
```

}

The appsettings.json  `"ActiveDirectorySettings": { "Tenant": "zzzzzz.onmicrosoft.com", "ClientId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "AppKey": "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy", "AADInstance": "https://login.windows.net/{0}", "ApiResourceId": "https://someurl.com", "ApiHost": "https://someurl.com" },`

It fails on the AuthenitcationContext and the error I get is as follows:

> Operation is not supported on this platform.
> System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on
> this platform.    at
> System.Net.Http.BrowserHttpHandler.set_Credentials(ICredentials value)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.set_UseDefaultCredentials(Boolean
> value)    at Microsoft.Identity.Core.Http.HttpClientFactory..ctor()
> at Microsoft.Identity.Core.Http.HttpManager..ctor(IHttpClientFactory
> httpClientFactory)    at
> Microsoft.Identity.Core.ServiceBundle..ctor(IHttpClientFactory
> httpClientFactory, IHttpManager httpManager, IWsTrustWebRequestManager
> wsTrustWebRequestManager, Boolean shouldClearCaches)    at
> Microsoft.Identity.Core.ServiceBundle.CreateWithHttpClientFactory(IHttpClientFactory
> httpClientFactory)    at
> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext..ctor(IServiceBundle
> serviceBundle, String authority, AuthorityValidationType
> validateAuthority, TokenCache tokenCache, IHttpClientFactory
> httpClientFactory)

In the startup.cs I am just using the default Http client:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });
```

I had previously added an HttpClientFactory but I still got the error. I haven't played with WASM much, so I am assuming that it cannot use **Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory**.

As  additional information, I am trying to contact a secure API that is hosted on Microsoft Dynamics. The auth works with Blazor Server, an MVC app and also a WPF app, so I am assuming the issue is that this method of authorization is not compatible with WASM.

Can anyone advise how or what I need to do.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

AuthenticationContext looks like a class from the [ADAL library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/). The latter has been deprecated for a while now.

**Move to [MSAL for Blazor WASM](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication).**

For more information take a look at [Blazor WebAssembly authentication.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#blazor-webassembly-authentication)